# What does the super() point to on earth?

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, super

In the post ,super() was described as: [describe super()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

```
super() looks at the next class in the MRO (method resolution order, accessed with cls.__mro__) to call the methods.
```

Some material even give a more clear definition as:
[more clear definition on super()](https://blog.titanwolf.in/a?ID=00750-dfcb794a-fd72-4449-99bf-eddca724c567)

```
def  super ( cls , inst ) : 
    mro = inst.__class__.mro( ) 
    return mro[mro.index( cls )  +  1 ]
```

Create a multiple inheritnce class struture as below:

```
class state():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class event():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class happystate(state,event):
    def __init__(self):
        print(super())
        print(super(happystate,self))
```

The mro list :

```
>>> happystate.__mro__
(<class '__main__.happystate'>, <class '__main__.state'>, <class '__main__.event'>, <class 'object'>)
```

The `super()` in `happystate` class will look at the next class in the MRO, it is `state` class in this status.

```
x=happystate()
<super: <class 'happystate'>, <happystate object>>
<super: <class 'happystate'>, <happystate object>>
```

Why `super()` in `happystate` class point to itself instead of the next class in MRO list----`state`?
If `super()` point to `state`,the output should be as:

```
x=happystate()
<super: <class 'state'>, <state object>>
<super: <class 'state'>, <state object>>
```

Comment: It doesn't point to itself, `super()` returns a `super object`.  Note the `<super: ` at the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't "point" to the same class, `super` is a class of its own:

```py
>>> super
<class 'super'>

>>> class happystate(state,event):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print(super(), type(super()))
... 
>>> happystate()
<super: <class 'happystate'>, <happystate object>> <class 'super'>
```

So you can also use it outside the class:

```
>>> super(happystate)
<super: <class 'happystate'>, NULL>
```

But inside the class it has some special behavior, so let's save it as an instance variable so we can interact with it a bit more:

```
>>> class happystate(state,event):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.s = super()
... 
>>> h = happystate()
>>> h.s.__self_class__
<class '__main__.happystate'>
>>> h.s.__thisclass__
<class '__main__.happystate'>                    # the class
>>> h.s.__self__                      
<__main__.happystate object at 0x7fa8a42642e0>   # the object of the class
```

But that still doesn't tell us much, so let's jump [at the docs for super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super):

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class.

So at the end of the day `super` is there to help you access stuff from the parent class(es) without having to traverse the MRO yourself, which means cleaner code. Let's use this newfound knowledge and modify your code a bit:

```py
class state():
    def __init__(self, x):
        print("state __init__", x)
        self.x = x

class event():
    def __init__(self):
        print("event __init__")

class happystate(state,event):
    def __init__(self):
        super(state, self).__init__()
        self.s = super()
```

Now let's try using the modified code:

```
>>> h = happystate()
event __init__        # surprise! It doesn't call `state` 
                      # (or its super - `object`) but the
                      # next in the MRO for `happystate`: `event`!

>>> h.s.__init__(3)   # calls state.__init__ (notice that we pass 1 argument)
state __init__ 3
>>> h.x               # state.__init__ received `h` as the `self` argument and updated it!
3
```

Answer (score 2):

`super()` returns an instance of a `super` class that tracks the current position in the MRO.  When calling a method on a `super` instance, `super` looks up the next class in the MRO and calls the method on that class.

Maybe this will help:

```py
class state():
    def __init__(self):
        print('state.__init__')
        print(super())
        super().__init__()

class event():
    def __init__(self):
        print('event.__init__')
        print(super())
        super().__init__()

class happystate(state,event):
    def __init__(self):
        print('happystate.__init__')
        print(super())
        super().__init__()

print(happystate.mro())
x = happystate()
```

Output:

```
[<class '__main__.happystate'>, <class '__main__.state'>, <class '__main__.event'>, <class 'object'>]
happystate.__init__
<super: <class 'happystate'>, <happystate object>>  # currently in happystate of happystate object
state.__init__                                      # state is next
<super: <class 'state'>, <happystate object>>       # now in state of happystate object.
event.__init__                                      # event is next
<super: <class 'event'>, <happystate object>>       # now in event of happystate object
```

This also illustrates that when using inheritance, all classes in the tree need to use `super()`.  Even though `event` doesn't have a base class, lack of `super().__init__()` would never call `state.__init__` when creating a `happystate`.