# What does method-wrapper '__init__' mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, super

super() returns an instance of a super class that tracks the current position in the MRO. When calling a method on a super instance, super looks up the next class in the MRO and calls the method on that class.

[Mark Tolonen give a explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69408900/what-does-the-super-point-to-on-earth)

```
class mon():
    def __init__(self):
        print("i am in mon's init")
        print(super())
        print(super().__init__)
        super().__init__()

class far():
    def __init__(self):
        print("i am in far's init")
        print(super())
        print(super().__init__)
        super().__init__()

class son(mon,far):
    def __init__(self):
        print("i am in son's init")
        print(super())
        print(super().__init__)
        super().__init__()
```

Show the MRO on `son` class.

```
son.__mro__
(<class '__main__.son'>, <class '__main__.mon'>, <class '__main__.far'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Initialize a `son` class to check what `super() is`  and `super().__init__` point to.

```
x = son()
i am in son's init
<super: <class 'son'>, <son object>>
<bound method mon.__init__ of <__main__.son object at 0x7ff0376f5c70>>
i am in mon's init
<super: <class 'mon'>, <son object>>
<bound method far.__init__ of <__main__.son object at 0x7ff0376f5c70>>
i am in far's init
<super: <class 'far'>, <son object>>
<method-wrapper '__init__' of son object at 0x7ff0376f5c70>
```

We draw conclusions:

1.super() returns an instance of a super class that tracks the current position in the MRO.
2.When calling a method on a super instance, super looks up the next class in the MRO and calls the method on that class, except the `far` class in this example.

The `super().__init__` in `far` class should point to `<class 'object'>`,what does `<method-wrapper '__init__' of son object` mean here?

```
<method-wrapper '__init__' of son object at 0x7ff0376f5c70>
```

Maybe the output should be:

```
<bound method object.__init__ of <__main__.son object at 0x7ff0376f5c70>>
```

If `super().__init__` means `son.__init__`,all info should output twice.